# How to sort a list in ascending order of its most significant digits in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting

How to sort a list in ascending order of its most significant digits?
I tried it with **radix sort**, but it is not working.

```
def sorrt(l, num, const, place):
    ne = []
    for i in range(10):
        ne.append([])

    for i in l:
        digit = (i // const) % 10
        ne[digit].append(i)

    new_list = [element for innerList in ne for element in innerList]
    return new_list

def sortmsd(l):
    num = max(l)
    place = 1
    const = 10 ** len(str(num))
    const = const // 10
    while (num // place > 0):
        l = sorrt(l, num, const, place)
        const = const // 10
        place *= 10
```

Output should be:

```
list = [237, 146, 259, 348, 152, 163, 235, 48, 36, 62, 147] # and the sorted list should be
list = [146, 147, 152, 163, 235, 237, 259, 348, 36, 48, 62]
```

Comment: Interested in what the use case is here for a lexicographic ordering of numbers, or is this simply an academic exercise?

Comment: Maybe you could make it clear - what do you mean by *most significant digits*?  We could guess, or read code, but rather you give a *formal* definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```py
lst = [237, 146, 259, 348, 152, 163, 235, 48, 36, 62, 147]

print(sorted(lst, key=str))
```

Prints:

```
[146, 147, 152, 163, 235, 237, 259, 348, 36, 48, 62]
```

---

EDIT:

I used `key=str` because I want to compare the items lexicographically (not numerically). E.g. I want "36" > "348" be `True` (which is in this case because the two values are strings)

Comment: @DanielHao I've added small explanation.